# OpenGL with QT: /usr/lib/libQtOpenGL.so not found

Tags: qt, opengl

I am trying to use an example application which uses OpenGL in QT, but when compiling I ger the following error:

```
:-1: error: error: /usr/lib/libQtOpenGL.so: No such file or directory
```

I do have the line `QT += opengl` in my pro file, so I was wondering what the problem might be  - is this an option I should have set when I initially compiled QT?

(On Ubuntu 11.10)

Comment: Did you install `libqt4-opengl-dev`?

Comment: What is a "pro file"? Do you mean "profile" or a file of type "pro"? If it's a "profile", then what kind of profile? Your Makefile? And if it's a file of type "pro", how do you use those to build?

Comment: @genpfault- it turns out I had, but your comment made me realise the obvious solution, which I'll post below. @Nicol a `pro` file is sort of a QT version of a cmake file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I did have the file on my system, but it had been put in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` for some reason. So I ran:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so /usr/lib
```

at the terminal, and all is well.

Comment: Sounds like the new(ish) [multiarch stuff](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) in Debian/Ubuntu.  You might want to at least use a symlink so that you can utilize any updates/upgrades that might occur down the line.